# Use ActiveModelSerializers with rawSQL query result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, active-model-serializers

I would like to use ActiveModelSerializers on the result of a rawSQL query in Rails.
Can't find a way to do it.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM table"
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(sql)
options = { each_serializer: MySerializer }
output = ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(results, options).as_json
```

I've tried several options:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

give a `PG::Result`

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(sql)
```

give a `ActiveRecords::Result`

But none of that can be serialized.

Comment: Do you have to use AMS, it is not maintained really anymore, other gems would be e.g. `blueprinter` or `jsonapi-serializer`

Answer (score 0):

*active_model_serializers doesn't seem to be supported so consider choosing another library.*

Hashes can't be serialized with your custom serializer, because they don't have `read_attribute_for_serialization`. So we can wrap hashes of `results` with such a class:

```rb
class SerializableHash
  def initialize(original_hash)
    @original_hash = original_hash
  end

  def read_attribute_for_serialization(attribute)
    @original_hash[attribute]
  end
end
```

After that they can be serialized:

```rb
sql = "SELECT * FROM table"
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(sql).map do |item|
  SerializableHash.new(item)
end

options = { each_serializer: UserSerializer }
output = ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(results, options).as_json
```

Answer (score 0):

*active_model_serializers doesn't seem to be supported so consider choosing another library.*

**This isn't the best way, monkey patching is not recommended**

Hashes can't be serialized with your custom serializer, because they don't have `read_attribute_for_serialization`. So the simplest way to solve this problem is to monkey patch the `Hash` class:

```rb
class Hash
  alias_method :read_attribute_for_serialization, :[]
end
```

Then it should work as expected:

```rb
sql = "SELECT * FROM table"
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(sql)
options = { each_serializer: UserSerializer }
output = ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(results, options).as_json
```